# Recursion and returns maintenance

Tags: c, recursion

```
while doing recursion how many stacks are maintained inside for example in C program of factorial ?
Is queue also maintained internally for recursion?

Function Implementation:

    if(x==1){ 

            return 1;

     }
     else{ 

          return x*facto(x-1); 
    }
```

If Stack is one and each frame consist of x*(x-1) till x==1 then how returns get multiplied by previous value..

```
in more simple way lets take a stack -->


       returns
|2(1)|---->    2(1) evaluates to 2
|3(2)|---->    3(2)<______________| evaluates to 6
|4(3)|---->    4(6)<______________| evaluates to 24
|5(4)|---->    5*(24)<____________| evaluates to 120
------         finally back to main...
```

so as i said earlier how are the returns maintained because to revert the previous calculated value it should be maintained internally right? ( or passed to successor )

Comment: Please show the implementation of the function.

Comment: if(x==1) 
      return 1;
else
        return x*facto(x-1);

//suppose x=5

Comment: There aren't a *number* of stacks, there is only one stack for each thread, and once it's full it's full. How many recursions that the stack can handle? That depends on the amount of data on the stack (i.e. the number and sizes of local variables and arguments) as well as on the actual of the size of the stack (which can vary from system to system).

Comment: And in your specific case, the number of recursions of course depends on the argument to the very first call.

Comment: not exactly what i am looking for see further explanation provided for the question??

below who so ever gave answer is going to different root

Answer (score 6):

You have just one stack. There will be several frames on the stack, every time the function is called a new frame will be added.

**Edit:** At least until there is no more available stack space, then you will get a StackOverflow :)

Comment: not exactly what i am looking for see further explanation provided for the question??

Comment: The stack keeps track of all variables within the function being executed. Besides this, it keeps track of what code is executed (stackpointer). When returning from a function call the result of that function will be filled in a placeholder. By using the stackpointer it knows where to continue executing code. These are the basics of how the stack works.

Comment: yes exactly,next question arises is when frame pops out of stack ,then stack pointer actually points to top element and it releases the memory at which it was pointing before popping..?? then how come it knows its predecessor and successor maintained variables in frame does the frames interact with each other with some source???

Comment: Correct, the frame is popped of the stack. By doing so the stack frees this space to be used again.